# Mavericks: How do you grant a created user the same permissions as the root user?

Tags: npm, root, sudo, chown

Instead of using `sudo` to install node modules; how do you make the administrative user the root user to install modules globally.

I've tried setting my current user as the admin and followed the steps outlined in the Apple website. [make user root](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14281)

This was unsuccessful

When installing modules, the computer receives this error:`npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the permissions on the directory that npm is trying to install things in. There is [documentation on the npm website](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).